# Numeric Search Box in Fusion Table with Mutliple Layers

Tags: google-fusion-tables

How are you all doing?

I'm a complete Fusion Tables API novice and I am stuck with the set-up of a search box. Here's my question:

Goal: I would like to create a map that shows the location of American football teams and the location of American football fan clubs in Belgium.

What I've done so far: This week I've started to create this map using two different overlays (coming from two different Fusion Tables: one 'Clubs' table with the American football teams and one 'Fans' table with the American football fan clubs).

I've also implemented two checkboxes that can turn each layer on and off.

Where I am stuck: As the number of fan clubs will start to grow in Belgium, I would like to add a search box that gives me the possibility to display only fan clubs with at least x number of members.

This "filter" would of course only apply to that single 'Fans' layer and the 'Teams' layer would need to remain unchanged.

In my 'Fans' Fusion Table I've got a column with the number of members per fan club.

Question: Is there any way to build such a 'search box' filter where if I type "50" in the search box it will only display the fan clubs with at least 50 members?

(So basically, the query I make to the table would be dependent of the value I enter in my search box.)

I've tried following the guidelines from several articles, but I am completely stuck:
http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/change_query_text_input.html
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/autocomplete

I've added the code I have so far in attachment. I would be so grateful if someone could help me out with this:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <h3>American Football in Belgium</h3>
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDjB2uAt9B6cFcUiJAgANg63qNQtiF6v24&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleLayer(this_layer){
      if(this_layer.getMap()) {
        this_layer.setMap(null)
      } else {
        this_layer.setMap(map);
      }
    }
   var layer1=null;
   var layer2=null;
   var map=null;

    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.809406, 4.498901),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: 'Fans Location',
          from:'1_n9DXwEAdVtmHhvypRxpjgk7DMJVbmBbYgsUfdQ'
        },
        map: map
      });
      layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: 'Club Location',
          from:'1waRLQMKE1bJKNT4qBesLQUNcjbezPeln6z1XQKA'
        },
        map: map
      });
    }
  </script></head>
  <body onload="initialize();">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="show_hide_layer1" checked onchange="toggleLayer(layer1)"/>
      <label> Fans </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="show_hide_layer2" checked onchange="toggleLayer(layer2)"/>
      <label> Clubs </label>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:80%; height:80%"></div>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Have a nice Saturday,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

The query you want is:

```
      query: {
        select: 'Fans Location',
        from:'1_n9DXwEAdVtmHhvypRxpjgk7DMJVbmBbYgsUfdQ',
        where: "'Number' > "+numFans
      }
```

on layer1, so:

```
    layer1.setOptions({
      query: {
        select: 'Fans Location',
        from:'1_n9DXwEAdVtmHhvypRxpjgk7DMJVbmBbYgsUfdQ',
        where: "'Number' > "+numFans
      }
    });
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_query.html)